# Relation between mean curvature and conformal metric

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

We'll consider $(N, g)$ a Riamannian Manifold and $\overline{g} = e^{2f}g$ a conformal metric. Let M be a hypersurface in N, $\overline{H}_M$ and $H_M$ the mean curvature of M with respect
to the metrics $\overline{g}$ and g, respectively. I would like some help to prove that

$$ \overline{H}_M = e^{-f}( H_M -2g( \nabla f, \eta)) $$

where $\nabla$ is the gradient with respect to metric g and $\eta$ is a normal vector field in M.

Comment: Your formula seems to be slightly off in a few ways.  For example, do you really want $\eta$ to be a *tangent* vector field to $M$ rather than the normal vector field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me use the transformation $\overline g = e^{2f}g$ to simplify some notations (and I guess your formula also use this convention). Near a point $p\in N,$ let $\{e_i\}$ be an orthonormal frame with respect to $g,$ and $\eta$ be a normal. Then with respect to $\overline g,$ we have $\overline e_i = e^{-f}e_i$ form an orthonormal frame near $p$ and $\overline\eta=e^{-f}\eta$ being the normal. Then
\begin{align}
\overline h_{ij}
& = \langle\overline\nabla_{\overline e_i}\overline e_j,\overline\eta \rangle_{\overline g}\\
& = e^{2f}\langle e^{-2f}\overline\nabla_{e_i}e_j, e^{-f}\eta\rangle_g\\
& = e^{-f}\langle \nabla_{e_i}e_j-\delta_{ij}\nabla f,\eta \rangle_g\\
& = e^{-f}( h_{ij} -\langle \nabla f,\eta\rangle_g\delta_{ij})\\
\end{align}
where we use the transformation of the Levi-Civita connection, i.e.,
$$\overline\nabla_X Y = \nabla_XY + (Xf)Y + (Yf)X - \langle X,Y\rangle_g\nabla f.$$
Thus
\begin{align}
\overline H 
& = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\overline h_{ii}\\
& = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}e^{-f}(h_{ii} - \langle \nabla f,\eta\rangle_g)\\
& = e^{-f} (H-(n-1) \langle \nabla f,\eta\rangle_g),
\end{align}
where $n$ is the dimension of $N,$ so in your case $n-1=2.$

Comment: A couple of comments to get a correct formula:  First, if $\bar g = \mathrm{e}^{2f} g$ and $\mathbf{e}_i$ is a $g$-orthonormal frame near $p$, then $\mathrm{e}^{-f} \mathbf{e}_i$ is a $\bar g$-orthonormal frame. (Note the minus sign.) Second, the *mean* curvature is the *average* of the principal curvatures, not the sum, so you are missing a normalization factor.  For example, check your formula for the unit sphere $M=S^{n-1}\subset\mathbb{E}^n$ with $g = |dx|^2$, $\mathrm{e}^{2f} = |x|^{-2}$, and $\eta$ the outward normal.  You should get $H=-1$ and $\bar H = 0$.

Comment: @Robert Bryant  Hello Robert. Thanks for your comment! Just one question. If $\overline g = e^{2f}g$ and $\overline e=e^{-f}e,$ isn't it correct that $\langle \overline e,\overline e\rangle_{\overline g} = e^{-2f}\langle e^{-f} e, e^{-f} e\rangle_{g} = e^{-4f}|e|^2_g?$

Comment: No, that is not correct.  $g$ is a a tensor of type $(0,2)$ while vector fields are tensors of type $(1,0)$.  Maybe you are confused by the notation $\langle X,Y \rangle_g$, which means $g(X,Y)$, so $\bar g(X,Y) = e^{2f} g(X,Y) = g(e^fX,e^fY)$.  In particular, if $g(X,X)=1$, then $\bar g(e^{-f}X,e^{-f}X) = 1$.

Comment: @RobertBryant So when people write $\overline g = e^{2f} g,$ it doesn't mean that locally $\overline g_{ij} = e^{2f}g_{ij}$ (which implies $\overline g^{ij} = e^{2f}g^{ij}$), is it?

Comment: I mean $\overline g^{ij} = e^{-2f}g^{ij}$ in the previous comment.

Comment: Yes, $\bar g = e^{2f} g$ means what you say, and also $\bar g^{ij} = -e^{2f} g^{ij}$, but that's not relevant. The point is that a vector field in local coordinates is $X = X^i\,\partial_i$, with $ |X|_g^2 = g_{ij}X^iX^j$.

Comment: @RobertBryant I have a minor remark on your first comment, where you write that 'the *mean* curvature is the *average* of the principal curvatures, not the sum'. In my opinion that is largely a matter of convention. For example, on the one hand do Carmo and Lee define it as the average, on the other hand Simon or Colding-Minicozzi use the convention where $H$ is the sum of the principal curvatures. Just a small point...

Comment: @LeoMoos:  There are two things:  There's the *definition* of mean curvature, which is the average of the principal curvatures.  There's also a convention about the notation $H$, which was classically used for the mean curvature, but nowadays is used by some to mean the sum of the principal curvatures, which is fine as long as they explicitly specify it.  I suppose some people don't mind calling the sum the mean, but that seems ill advised to me.  In any case, the OP explicitly specified that they mean $H$ to be the *mean* curvature, so I assumed they really meant it.

Comment: @RobertBryant I agree that calling the sum of the principal curvatures the *mean* curvature is slightly absurd, but this convention is not infrequent. In addition to the people I mention above, the mean curvature is also defined as the sum in Mantegazza's book on mean curvature flow. Mantegazza even adds the following remark 'Despite its name, [the mean curvature] is the *sum* of the eigenvalues of the second fundamental form, not their average mean'. As I said, it's a very minor point, that I'm mainly raising for students who might not be aware of the different conventions.

Comment: I edit the typo on the conformal factor and (hopefully) find the correct formula. As for the definition of the mean curvature, I have also seen two different definitions.