# Mean curvature under conformal transformation

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm reading this answer:[Relation between mean curvature and conformal metric](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382370/relation-between-mean-curvature-and-conformal-metric).

I wonder why we need to use a new orthonormal frame in the new metric to calculate the new second fundamental form?I don't think second fundamental form must be calculated in orthonormal frame.

Any help will be thanked.

Comment: I think the point is that with an orthonormal frame the *mean* curvature is just $H = \sum_i h_{ii}$ (or $H = \frac{1}{n} \sum_i h_{ii}$, depending on the convention). In a general frame $H = \operatorname{tr}_g A = g^{ij}h_{ij}$, with summation over repeated indices. (Again, depending on your convention, you'd have to normalize by $n$ here too.)

Comment: For that particular answer: read the commends and discussion between the OP and Robert Bryant. The problem is that it is very easy to make a mistake (between covariance and contravariance) in these types of calculations, and sometimes it is easier to re-base using a new frame then trying to remember exactly where the $e^{2f}$ go in every single step.